# Avoid Duplicate Vertices in Extruded Text

Tags: python, mesh, scripting, vertices, text-object

By default, new text objects are created with duplicate vertices.  When the curve is converted to a mesh, those extra vertices disappear.  However, if an extrusion value is added, the curve-to-mesh conversion does not remove the duplicate vertices.

[image: Animated GIF Demonstration]

Each letter ends up being comprised of disjointed sets of faces.  This might be a bug / oversight in `bpy.types.Curve.fill_mode = 'BOTH'` (the default value) which calls for the three sets of faces to be created independently.

[image: Animated GIF Demonstration]

Are there any fast and elegant methods of creating extruded text meshes without duplicate vertices?

Comment: I am creating text objects in a script and want to avoid using operators. It loops hundreds of times and needs to be fast.  With that in mind, I would be happy if an answer involved a code snippet that quickly and elegantly removes these extra vertices.

Comment: Why not do conversion first and then extrude as mesh or solidify it?